# Run WPF Application from another project as a reference

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an tool from a company that went out of business, but I still find the tool extremely useful.  The only issue is that after a set amount of time, it just crashes.  I suspect it's an unhandled exception from some worker thread.

The tool is a .NET 4.6 WPF application.  I have very little (read approaching zero) experience with WPF as I mainly use Winforms.  In a Winforms app I would creating a wrapper executable that references the tool's exe file, add a ThreadException handler to the Application context, and run the tool exe's main.  But that doesn't appear to be how WPF works.

Is there any way I could wrap the tool exe and catch those exceptions in WPF?

Comment: I can't say I recommend starting a WPF application in-proc inside a WinForms `.exe` - I know you _can_ make it work, but I just think it's asking for trouble. What I recommend you do instead is to create a new empty WPF project, and from there you can reference and lload the target application's `App` object and other XAML all in-proc there, including wiring-up all kinds of unhandled-exception-catchers.

Comment: That said, why not just dissassemble+decompile their program and rebuild it from source? That way you can make proper fixes to their code instead of trying to mitigate them.

Comment: Exceptions are local to the process they are thrown in. How is your app supposed to handle exceptions that are thrown in a separate process?